# Why can't I access a method in ruby initialize return object?

Tags: ruby, sketchup

I made a class to show a dialog in [sketchup](http://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/webdialog.php), and the web dialog has methods such as `show`, `close`. In the `initialize` method, I return the web dialog object, and call:

```
$loginUI=LoginUI.new
$loginUI.show # it tell me no this method
```

Why can't I access the `WebDialog` method and get the object as the return value unless I rewrite that method as follows?

```
class LoginUI
  @@me=nil
  def initialize()
    @@me=intiLoginDlg()
    @@me.show()
    return @@me
  end
  def intiLoginDlg()
    @dl = UI::WebDialog.new("aaa", true, "bbb", 50, 50, 0, 0, false);
    #...do something
    return @dl
  end
  ################################# I must add this method to trigger it??
  def isShow()
    return @@me.visible?
  end
  def show()
    @@me.show
  end
  def close
    @@me.close
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but I think the magic you are looking for is simply this:

```
class LoginUI < UI::WebDialog
  # initialize() and intiLoginDlg
end
```

If you do this, then:

```
$loginUI=LoginUI.new
$loginUI.show
```

...should work as expected.

Another much more advanced (and probably over-engineered!) solution that uses encapsulation instead of sub-classing would be to experiment with [`method_missing`](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/2-metaprogramming-ruby/chapters/25-dynamic-methods/lessons/66-method-missing).

Comment: To add to that - returning anything from Ruby's `initialize` method doesn't have any use. The return value is not returned when you call `.new` - you will always get an instance of the class.